# Select latest data per group from joined tables

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables like this:

```
survey:
survey_id | store_code | timestamp

product_stock:
survey_id | product_code | production_month | value
```

How can I get latest value, based on survey timestamp and grouped by store_code, product_code, and production_month?

for example if I have

```
survey_id | store_code | timestamp
1           store_1      2015-04-20
2           store_1      2015-04-22
3           store_2      2015-04-21
4           store_2      2015-04-22

survey_id | product_code | production_month | value
1           product_1      2                  15
2           product_1      2                  10
1           product_1      3                  20
1           product_2      2                  12
3           product_2      2                  23
4           product_2      2                  17
```

It'd return result like this

```
survey_id | store_code | time_stamp | product_code | production_month | value
2           store_1      2015-04-22   product_1      2                  10
1           store_1      2015-04-20   product_1      3                  20
1           store_1      2015-04-20   product_2      2                  12
4           store_2      2015-04-22   product_2      2                  17
```

and it needs to be as fast as possible, seeing the database is quite large in size

Comment: What do you mean by "get latest value, based on survey timestamp" ? I don't get this part of your question.

Comment: sorry for the bad english, not a native speaker... i mean selecting latest row based on survey's timestamp column.

Comment: So you want only the latest row to be selected ? One line result?

Comment: yup, grouped by store_code, product_code, and production month

Comment: Ok 1 line result. And what "based on survey's timestamp" means ? Maybe you ask for records with the most recent timestamp ?

Comment: well, latest based on the date on timestamp column

Comment: Your DB schema needs some modification. The timestamp needs to be on the 2nd table, timestamp in the first table does not help getting the latest data per group from the 2nd table. If there is a auto-incremented primary key in the 2nd table that could also help.

Comment: actually there is an auto-incremented primary key on the 2nd table, product_stock_id. I could also add the timestamp column to the 2nd table if need be.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED** - please run query again

Here is my answer:

```
SELECT survey.survey_id, survey.store_code, survey.timestamp, product_stock.survey_id, product_stock.product_code, product_stock.production_month, product_stock.value 
FROM survey 
INNER JOIN product_stock
ON survey.survey_id = product_stock.survey_id
WHERE survey.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
               FROM survey)
GROUP BY survey.store_code,product_stock.product_code,product_stock.production_month;
```

Comment: it seems to return 0 row if I include the where clause, and if I take it out it returns the first occurence of each group

Comment: UPDATED - please run query again.